# Can I Get any Item in specific language

Tags: jss, graphql

I am working on implementing tagging on the website, where we require English values for certain fields while the site is in `Arabic`. We retrieve items through `GraphQL`. For some components, we have employed custom content resolvers, which have effectively handled the task. However, there are certain components that are based on `GraphQL`, presenting a challenge.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into language fallback?

Comment: Yeah it is useful if the content is not available in Arabic

Comment: Isn't that what you're asking in the post?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please maybe try below?

```
query SignupForm($datasource: String!, $language: String!) {
  item(path: $datasource, language: $language) {
    name
    ... on SignUpForm {
      tagTemplate {
        targetItems {
          ... on GTMAttributeFolder {
            children {
              GTMAttributes: results {
                ... on GTMAttribute {
                  key {
                    value(language: "en") # Specify English language for key
                  }
                  value {
                    value
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That might work and help.

Comment: I tested this didn't work

Comment: @MuddassirPasta could you please maybe raise the Sitecore ticket to get the correct query by my understanding you are already in some specific language context when you are working on the children and now there you want to change the language which might be complex to get.

Or you can use static props to GrapghQL to get the item details component as that would be faster to work on in this case.

Comment: Hi @nikhil Sure I check with Sitecore support
Any How I fetched another Item with hardcoded language that did my job for now.
By this I am getting multiple Items now for different level tagging.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with search graphql query, it will provide results of the item in all the languages item version available.

**Sample Query:**

```
                 query {
                   search(
                    where: {
                      AND: [
                        {
                          name: "_path"
                          value: "{A25332F7-EB20-4CD3-A27B-C29C1FB9635B}"
                          operator: CONTAINS
                        }                           
                      ]
                    }
                    # defaults to 10
                    first: 10                      
                  ) {
                    total
                    pageInfo {
                      endCursor
                      hasNext
                    }
                    results { 
                      
                      ... data
                       name: field(name: "title",) {
                         value
                        }
                    }
                  }
                }                   
                
            fragment data on Item {
              language 
              {
                displayName
              }
              ... on OnboardingPage {
                title {
                  value
                }
              }
              url {
                path
              }
            }
```

**Response**

```
    {
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "total": 2,
      "pageInfo": {
        "endCursor": "Mg==",
        "hasNext": false
      },
      "results": [
        {
          "language": {
            "displayName": "English (Australia) : English (Australia)"
          },
          "title": {
            "value": "AppUpdate-AU"
          },
          "url": {
            "path": "/mobilehome/appupdate"
          },
          "name": {
            "value": "AppUpdate-AU"
          }
        },
        {
          "language": {
            "displayName": "English : English"
          },
          "title": {
            "value": "AppUpdate-EN"
          },
          "url": {
            "path": "/mobilehome/appupdate"
          },
          "name": {
            "value": "AppUpdate-EN"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Is there anyway to extend the Item Query with required parameter??

Comment: @MuddassirPasta are you looking for updating the GraphQL schema itself to support this?, if the above search query not works for you then, cant you try the below item query see if this helps Request: ` query { English:item(language:"en", path:"{A0BFA9A4-AC59-49A5-B169-1964EE39FA64}") { field(name:"Title") { value } } Australia:item(language:"en-AU", path:"{A0BFA9A4-AC59-49A5-B169-1964EE39FA64}") { field(name:"Title") { value } }} Response: { "data": { "English": { "field": { "value": "Home  Crawler" } }, "Australia": {"field": { "value": "Aus content" } } }}`

Comment: I tested the same

It was reverteing the previous item as well on the last language